# Random sharp edges when adding the Subdivision Surface "it's made 100% out of faces with 4 vertices and there are no double faces, edges or vertices

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

I have this problem when adding the Subdivision Surface to my figure, it doesn't seem to smooth certain edges and I made sure that the figure was made completely out of 4 vertice faces and I also made sure that there where any random repeated hidden vertices or faces or edges so I don't know where the problem is at all.

[image: as you can see there are sharp edges]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the wireframe?

Comment: is this what you meant? thanks for your time btw

Comment: The issue is that you have edge loops with tight spacing in these areas. In combination with a subsurface modifier this will cause sharper edges compared to the other areas.

Comment: i don't understand, because the edges are not "less smoothed", they are just sharp as if the subdivision surface simply had missed them

Comment: You can take a look at where the subsurface modifier adds faces by changing the viewport shading to wireframe. Due to the current topology it will accumulate faces in the problematic areas. I would suggest you take a look at some reference images how the edge loops in face are connected to each other to avoid these problems. http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/FaceTopology